# Agregar Strings dinámicamente a una cadena sin perder los valores anteriores

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde con un número determinado de filas y columnas genere automáticamente mediante JQuery con la libreria [JQuery-Seat-Charts](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts).

En principio consigo hacer perfectamente esta generación mediante funciones por **AJAX** que envían la petición a la aplicación y por Java; creo el mapa que requiere la libreria.

Un ejemplo de asientos sería el siguiente:

```
[
    'aaa___aaa',
    'aaaa_aaaa',
    'aaaa_aaaa'
]
```

Donde las 'a' serían asientos y las '_' huecos. El problema que tengo está en la generación automática de números que tiene la propia libreria ya que el usuario final quiere poder asignarle a mano los números, para ello la librería cuenta con un recurso para sobrescribir estos números directamente en el mapa tal que así:

```
[
    'a[,NUMBUTACA1]a[,NUMBUTACA1]a___a[,NUMBUTACA1]aa',
    'aaaa_aaaa[,JUST_LABEL1]',
    'aaaa_aaaa'
]
```

Y por fin aquí viene la pregunta: actualmente guardo el mapa en un String de Java y después habilito una función para que el usuario vaya numerando las butacas el mismo, con lo que tengo que, detrás de cada 'a' agregar los corchetes necesarios para ello. El problema es que actualmente, para hacer cualquier modificación en las butacas, estoy leyendo el String tomando sus posiciones (separando las líneas con saltos de línea e iterando el String por cada letra de la línea) tal que así:

```
    String[] lineas = mapa.split(SALTO_LINEA);
    String[] pos = posicion.split("_");
    int fila = Integer.valueOf(pos[0]) - 1;
    int columna = Integer.valueOf(pos[1]) - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < lineas.length; i++) {
        String linea = lineas[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < linea.length(); j++) {
            if (i == fila && j == columna) {
                if (linea.charAt(j) == 'a') {
                    resultado += HUECO;
                } else {
                    resultado += ASIENTO;
                }
            } else {
                resultado += linea.charAt(j);
            }
        }
        resultado += SALTO_LINEA;
    }
```

y veo que si empiezo a añadir los corchetes detrás de cada asiento esto ya no me va a servir ya que en el caso de, por ejemplo, `a[,2]_aa` para tocar la última butaca tendría que sumarle a la posición real 4 para que coincida.

**¿Cómo podría ir añadiendo estos corchetes sin ver comprometidas las posiciones?** (o si hay alguna función ya sea en Java o en JQuery donde pueda hacer esto de una forma más o menos eficiente).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi recomendación es que no trabajes sobre formatos inadecuados y que realices las conversiones oportunas (normalmente basta con de A a B y de B a A).

No he entendido muy bien el problema concreto, pero básicamente te sugiero que representes tus datos de forma cómoda para operar con ellos, por ejemplo tu sala podría ser un array de array de objetos butaca.

Supongamos las butacas

```
function Butaca(tipo, num) {
  this.tipo = tipo;
  this.num = num || null;
  this.toFormat = function () { return tipo + (!this.num ? "": "[" + this.num + "]") };
}
```

donde `toFormat` convierte esa butaca a la representación que sea (en tu caso algo como `_` o `a[34]` o lo que sea que necesites (que no tengo claro).

Ahora, para convertir la cadena a tu representación puedes hacer

```
// dado el formato indicado parsea y devuelve un array de objetos butaca
function parseaButacas(butacas_string) {
  var mx, rx = /([a_])(?:\[([0-9]+)\])?/g, rs = [];
  while(mx = rx.exec(butacas_string)) {
    rs.push(new Butaca(mx[1], mx[2]));
  }
  return rs;
}
```

y lo mismo para, dado un array de butacas, generar la cadena final

```
// dado un array de butacas, devuelve el formato indicado
function formateaButacas(butacas) {
  return butacas.map(function (b) { return b.toFormat() }).join('');
}
```

con ésto, podemos ver un ejemplo (que además sirve de test) que verifica la invarianza de la identidad resultante de combinar las dos conversiones anteriores (si tienes A lo pasas a B y ese B lo pasas a A entonces tienes lo mismo que al principio si todo ha salido bien).

```
// un test de invarianza
var ejemplo = 'a[34]a[27]a___a[85]aa';
var devuelta = formateaButacas(parseaButacas(ejemplo));
console.log(ejemplo == devuelta);
```

Con ésto, ahora puedes trabajar fácilmente con tus butacas porque son objetos en un array.

NOTA: el array de ejemplo, resulta en:

```
Butaca { tipo="a",  num="34" }
Butaca { tipo="a",  num="27" }
Butaca { tipo="a",  num=null }
Butaca { tipo="_",  num=null }
Butaca { tipo="_",  num=null }
Butaca { tipo="_",  num=null }
Butaca { tipo="a",  num="85" }
Butaca { tipo="a",  num=null }
Butaca { tipo="a",  num=null }
```

Comment: El ejemplo es perfecto la verdad, solo me faltaría saber como hacer el parseButacas en java en lugar de Javascript, concretamente esta línea,   `var mx, rx = /([a_])(?:\[([0-9]+)\])?/g, rs = [];` ya que no se como representarla en un Pattern de java

Comment: @Raider, esa expresión regular funciona igualmente en Java (por fortuna), de todos modos, dado que esa representación final la necesitas para jQuery-Seat-Charts parece más adecuado hacer `formateaButacas` sólo para mostrar el gráfico (y `parseaButacas` para obtener un posible cambio) con lo que al servidor no enviaría información en un formato tan "tosco".

Comment: A parte de necesitar la representación para la libreria, tal como esta diseñada la aplicación (no es cosa mia) tambien la necesito guardar en la base de datos con ese formato, de ahi que quisiera hacerdo directamente en java